# С прописной или со строчной Восток?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная

> Ранняя христианская живопись и скульптура главным образом запечатлела 
>   сцены ученичества или чудес, совершённых верой. Но к VII веку **на
>   Востоке бывшей империи – в Византии начинают появляться так называемые
>   подлинные изображения Христа**, а затем и святых, и Богородицы.
>   Чудотворные лики – таинственные отпечатки или изображения, принесённые
>   ангелами, или запечатленные самим Лукой, или списки – их копии,
>   вызвали многотысячные паломничества.

И не скучно ли одинокому тире перед Византией?

Comment: Во многих текстах фигурирует Восток Римской империи или Восточная Римская империя (как определение Византии), поэтому с большой буквы - нормально. http://frank-history.limarevvn.ru/2g.htm https://w.histrf.ru/articles/article/show/vizantiia Второе тире - надо.

Comment: Угу. Плавно перетекай в ответ. )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считаю так: *на Востоке* — с прописной; *в Византии* — в двух тире (или в двух запятых); *их копии* — в скобках (иначе возникает ощущение, что "чудотворные лики их копии, вызвали многотысячные паломничества").

Но к VII веку на Востоке бывшей империи – в Византии – начинают появляться так называемые подлинные изображения Христа, а затем и святых, и Богородицы. Чудотворные лики – таинственные отпечатки или изображения, принесённые ангелами, или запечатленные самим Лукой, или списки (их копии) – вызвали многотысячные паломничества.

[**Падение Западной Римской империи**](http://rushist.com/index.php/tutorials/kareev-tutanc/1052-padenie-zapadnoj-rimskoj-imperii):
*...фактически разделение Востока и Запада повело к образованию двух разных империй, из которых одна позднее сделалась совершенно греческою (по государственному языку, бывшему прежде латинским) и гораздо чаще называется нами Византийскою, чем Восточною Римскою.*

Answer (score 1):

> сцены ученичества

Спорно. Ученичество — пребывание в положении ученика.

> запечатлела сцены ученичества или чудес

Христианская живопись запечатлела и сцены "ученичества", и сцены чудес, так почему *или*? Вариант правки: **сцены ученичества и чудес**

> а затем и святых, и Богородицы

Первое *и* усилительное, второе — соединительное, **запятая  не нужна.**

> ...списки – их копии, вызвали многотысячные паломничества.

Согласен с Риммой: **...списки (их копии) – вызвали многотысячные паломничества.**

> Чудотворные лики... вызвали многотысячные паломничества.

*Вызвали* звучит плохо, по-моему. *Многотысячные паломничества* - это как?!  Много паломничеств, каждое — многотысячное?! Варианты правки: **притягивали тысячи паломников; были целью тысяч паломников.**